# Disabling the "Enable notifications?" popup in Firefox

Tags: firefox, notifications

If I'm on a page that has web notifications (like Slack or others), Firefox asks me if I want to enable them. However, my choices are "Yes" or "Ignore for now". The problem is, if I select "Ignore", every time there is a notification it asks me again. This is incredibly annoying.

How do I disable this completely? (I would accept disabling this feature entirely if that's easiest.)

Comment: If you want to see a checkbox in Firefox for this, then please be sure to vote for [bug #1368744](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1368744) in the Firefox bug tracker. (Don't nag in comments on the bug tracker; use the Vote button.)

Comment: On a site-by-site basis: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox#w_upgraded-notifications

Comment: Would you consider changing the accepted answer to one that is relevant for Firefox 59 and later?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Go into `about:config` and set `dom.webnotifications.enabled` to `false`

You can also disable this on a per-site basis by right-clicking somewhere in a blank spot of the site (or pressing Ctrl-I on Windows or Cmd-I on Mac) and then selecting "View Page Info" from the opening menu. This opens a window with a "Permissions" tab. Scroll down until you see "Receive Notifications", uncheck "Use Default" then select "Block."

[image]

Comment: Downvoted. This does not answer the question. @pandemonium provided the correct answer to the specific question. It would be appropriate to give that user the Answer credit.

Comment: It was such a relief to disable these pesky notifications. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyG You don't seem to have read the question.

Comment: The original incorrect response was posted in 2015. In 9/17 I downvoted that. By that time @Pandemonium had posted the correct answer, but the OP hasn't been back to fix the accepted answer.

Note that in 12/17 Chin then edited his answer to be the correct one, having seen the correct answer by Pandemonium.

Now, I dunno whether to stand by my downvote because this answer was credited incorrectly, and perhaps Chin is still taking credit for what was originally a wrong answer, or if I should remove the downvote because in good spirit Chin corrected himself. Leaving it until clarified.

Comment: @TonyG, I am in complete agreement with you.  It seems to be rather inappropriate for this answer to be modified *years* later to include the answer from Pandemonium which obviously works much better.  From my perspective, that seems to be unprofessional at best, and it borders on being both manipulative and deceptive.

Answer (score 80):

Go into `about:config` and set `dom.webnotifications.enabled` to `false`. This seems to work for me in FF 47.

Comment: This is real solution !!!!!!!

Comment: Still works in FF v52. So silly that they don't have a setting about it in the normal preferences. Oh well, the web is going south....

Comment: This seems to be the only working solution by now! I've seen elsewhere lots of references to a "Preferences - Contents Windows - Notifications - Do not disturb" button, which seems to not exist anymore, at least in FF 55. It's been very annoying having most websites I visit requiring all my attention to first choose to enable or not notifications, one by one.

Comment: also works in firefox 57 quantum

Answer (score 24):

### As of Firefox 59, this is in Options

#### Open the Options window

[image]

#### On the left side of the screen, click "Privacy & Security"

[image]

#### Under the "Permissions" section, find "Notifications" and click the "Settings..." button

[image]

#### Check the box that says "Block new requests asking to allow notifications"

[image]

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer

Answer (score 13):

In `about:config` I set `dom.webnotifications.enabled` to `false` but it didn't work for me in FF 56.  I had to set `dom.push.enabled` to `false` as well.

Comment: That's the right answer!