# Why firefox forgets my web notifications for Twitter

Tags: firefox, browser, notifications

*Why Firefox forgets my web notifications for Twitter, every-time I restart my system.*

And I have failed to understand this weird behavior not less than 10 times. Just curious to know if this is a Firefox bug or am I missing something.

I have also read [Firefox Support for Push Notifications](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/push-notifications-firefox) & [Disable Web Notifications](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1140700)

Attached are the screenshots to make it more clear.

1. First one, is for the Twitter Web Notification
2. Second one, is for the Firefox Notification Setting

[image: Twitter Notification]
[image: Firefox Notification]

**FYI:**

- It never happened with Chrome but it eats lot of my cache memory, so I removed it.
- I have also updated firefox to 58.0.2, but nothing improved.
- Also, checked this answer [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/959269/disabling-the-enable-notifications-popup-in-firefox)

Any help/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution yesterday, when I was checking some of my `Background Apps` in Windows 10. And I found Twitter was turned off.

So, just **Turn it On** and you are good to go. :)

```
Settings > Privacy > Background Apps > Twitter
```